# タグ [swift] のデフォルトハイライト表示を lang-swift にしたい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, シンタックスハイライト

[swift](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) タグについているデフォルトのコードハイライト設定を default から lang-swift に変更して頂きたいです。

["What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/341401) に書かれているように、これは存在するハイライト設定です。また、本家 Stack Overflow における [swift タグ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swift/info) の設定は lang-swift になっています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

lang-swift に変更しました。

> [image]